# Change file's owner when copying resources with testcontainers

Tags: java, docker, unit-testing, testcontainers

I'm using testcontainers in Java tests. To configure application in container I need to put and mount configuration files: some files are static, so I'm mounting them using `withClassPathResourceMapping` when creating new container:

```
container.withClassPathResourceMapping(
  "/path/to/res",
  "/etc/app/config.name",
  BindMode.READ_ONLY
)
```

Other files are generated dynamically and could be overridden by app in container, so I'm copying the content to container using `copyFileToContainer` after container start:

```
container.copyFileToContainer(
 Transferable.of(bin /* byte[] */),
 "/var/app/resource.name"
)
```

The app is running in container as `app:app` user and group which are defined in the `Dockerfile`.

And I have two similar problems here:

1. `withClassPathResourceMapping` operation creates missed directory if not found, e.g. classpath mapping for `"/etc/app/config.name"` creates `"/etc/app/` directory. But it creates these directories as `root:root` user, so app can't create new files in this directory later
2. the files which are copied into container using `copyFileToContainer` are not read-only and can be modified by app. But `copyFileToContainer` creates files as `root:root` user, so app can't write to these files.

I tried to exec `chown -R /path` after container start but this command fails, since the exec user is not a `root`.

What is the correct way to setting owner and permissions in testcontainers?